# ASP.NET Core on request before started middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I have an asp.net core application and I need to add elastic logging, I decided to use Serilog for it, but I need to add a Correlation id into logs messages, I can't do it within only HTTP correlation id header because I have service bus handlers that also need to have correlation id. So I did it with default asp request middleware, but still have logs without it

request finished/started logs aren't have correlation id

[image: request finished/started logs aren't have correlation id]

here is my serilog setup

```
hostBuilder.UseSerilog(
            (_, _, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(ConfigureElasticSink(configuration, environment))
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);
            });
```

and request middleware

```
public class CorrelationIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorrelationIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ICorrelationIdService correlationIdService)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Constants.CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME, out var correlationId);
        correlationIdService.Set(correlationId);
        context.Request.Headers.TryAdd(Constants.CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME, correlationIdService.CorrelationId);
        LogContext.PushProperty(Constants.CORRELATION_ID, correlationIdService.CorrelationId);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

UDP

My startup file

```
using IM360.Logger;
using InMarket360EmailServiceWebApi.WebUI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLoggerServices();
builder.Services.AddWebUIServices();

builder.Host.UseExternalLogging();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseExternalLogging(); //middleware being added in this extension method

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();

public partial class Program { }
```

Logger extenstions file

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddLoggerServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<ICorrelationIdService, CorrelationIdService>();
            serviceCollection.AddHeaderPropagation(opt => opt.Headers.Add(Constants.CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME));

            return serviceCollection;
        }

        public static WebApplication UseExternalLogging(this WebApplication webApplication)
        {
            webApplication.UseMiddleware<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();
            webApplication.UseHeaderPropagation();

            return webApplication;
        }
```

Have any ideas?

Comment: Can you also include your startup.cs file? The order in which the middleware are added to the pipeline is important. From your log it looks like the start and end of the requests are not logged, meaning you might have a middleware that logs the start and end of the requests which is added to the pipeline before the correlationId middleware.

Comment: Hm.. Startup.cs looks fine to me. Sorry. I don't see what's causing the problem..